# horizontal ScrollView bounces back issue programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a simple `ScrollView` with 4 `buttons` inside of it and I would like to make that a `horizontal ScrollView`.

This is how I set it up:

```
let itemScrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let v = UIScrollView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .red
    return v
}()
```

And I constrain it and its content like this:

```
itemView.addSubview(itemScrollView)
itemScrollView.addSubview(imageButton)
itemScrollView.addSubview(priceButton)
itemScrollView.addSubview(linkButton)
itemScrollView.addSubview(noteButton)
self.addSubview(dropDownButton)

itemView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true

dropDownButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
dropDownButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
dropDownButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
dropDownButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

itemScrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.topAnchor).isActive = true
itemScrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
itemScrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: dropDownButton.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
itemScrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

imageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
imageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
imageButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
imageButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemScrollView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true

priceButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
priceButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
priceButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
priceButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true

linkButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
linkButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
linkButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
linkButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: priceButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true

noteButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
noteButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
noteButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: itemScrollView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
noteButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: linkButton.leadingAnchor, constant: 45).isActive = true
```

In the end it looks like this, exactly how I want it (4th button is hidden behind the `dropDownButton`), but you can only scroll *vertical*.

[image]

**Update:**

By adding this line of code, I can scroll horizontally:

```
v.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
```

However now the problem is that it always "bounces back" to the left after scrolling. How can I fix that issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to conform your view controller to `UIScrollViewDelegate`, set `scrollView.delegate = self` and implement the [`scrollViewDidScroll`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619392-scrollviewdidscroll) method like this:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y != 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry not working :( with this you can't scroll at all

Comment: I updated my answer, you might want to have a look at that :)

Comment: It sounds like the width of your `scrollView` is not constrained to be the same as the width of the screen. You might want to change this. The scroll view can only be scrolled horizontally if the width of the `scrollView.contentView` is higher than the width of the scroll view itself.

Comment: not quite following you there. The `scrollView` is the *red*  `view`  in the picture. Why should I constrain to be the same width of the screen?

Comment: and what exactly is contentView in my case ?

Comment: My apologies, I've completely missed that part. I'm not sure what it is then, because it really sounds like something is wrong with content view constraints/content size. Quote [from the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview): "The scroll view must know the size of the content view so it knows when to stop scrolling; by default, it “bounces” back when scrolling exceeds the bounds of the content." You could try "playing" with the `contentSize` property manually to see if it changes anything.

Comment: that was it.. changed the `contentSize` manually and it works now. Not a very clean solution though :/